# How do I display all my results for a specific search. When the specific search has multiples results. Not using vLookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a sheet with 2 columns. ID and SearchTerm

ID has the same ID# for multiple SearchTerms.

I am trying to search for example ID# 25 and then be able to show all results on a separate sheet. Without having to search for the ID number and then Copy and Paste the columb.

I tried doing a vLookup, but it only gives me back the first SearchTerm based on the ID.

Comment: I can think of one way to do it with a formula, but you would need to copy the formula down X number of rows.  You would set the formula up to return "" when the number of rows copied down exceeds search results.   If you know you will never have more than 100 results, you could set it up initially for 100 rows.  Example data would be very helpful in terms of providing a potential answer.

Comment: @ForwardEd I have in Column A: ID numbers starting with 1-2000 and then in Column B I have 7225 different search terms that are all different.

Comment: Column A could have the ID # as 4. But for the ID # 4 it has 17 different terms. I want to be able to show all those terms with a single formula. Rather than copy and pasting.

Comment: I am also fine with having to copy the formula for X number of rows

Comment: you can also run an advanced filter, which would allow this.  vba will do it on command.  Formulas will be live but the number of array type formulas that would be needed would cause a major slow down on the calc time and every time a change is made the user would have to wait till it calculates till moving on to the next cell.

Comment: This'll get you the first 100 matches if you enter it as an array (ctrl+shift+enter):
`=INDEX(B1:B7225,SMALL(IF(A1:A7225=4,ROW(A1:A7225)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))))`
But like Scott says, it'll slow things down. A VBA solution would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your search ID in in E4 and you want your search results to be in F4:F21.  In F4 place the following formula and copy it down the maximum number row you think you might have.

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(B$1:B$7225)/((A$1:A$7255)=E4),ROW(A1)))
```

I was going to put a caveat in about don't use full column references within the AGGREGATE function because it performs array calculations and will slow things down, but I believe Scott Craner's comment covered that.

Having said all that I believe using filters is the faster approach.

UPDATE

In order to avoid errors from being displayed, wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(B$1:B$7225)/((A$1:A$7255)=E4),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

For only 7225 rows of data, an array formula isn't too bad, speed-wise (enter it as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a range that is 100 rows long and one column wide):

```
=INDEX(B1:B7225,SMALL(IF(A1:A7225=4,ROW(A1:A7225)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))))
```

Change the `4` to the desired search value (or a cell with the desired search value). You can get more/less than 100 results by changing the `100`.

I just tested it against a non-array version that you fill down, e.g.,

```
=INDEX(B1:B7225,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(B$1:B$7225)/((A$1:A$7255)=4),ROW(A1)))
```

and the array version is more than an order of magnitude faster.